# How to re enable paste protection in Chrome console?

Tags: google-chrome

I have disabled the paste protection in Chrome console. How can I re enable this feature?

Comment: I've never heard of "paste protection" - what is it?

Comment: It will prevent you from pasting into your console. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587864/disable-paste-protection-in-chrome-devtools related.

Comment: FWIW, it didn't work for me when I tried it just now (see my post on that other QA)

Comment: The flag is set for me even after I disable the feature. Maybe that flag is not related?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible in the strictest sense; there doesn't appear to be a way to "reset" the warning without using a new Chrome profile. The Chrome docs indicate that once you disable the warning ["_you won't be bothered with self-XSS warnings ever again_"](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/self-xss#is_that_a_one-time_setting); they also note on that same page that the heuristic used is just based on having a console history (i.e. running at least 5 console commands prior to pasting code), but from my own experimentation clearing your console history doesn't seem to reset it.

Answer (score 28):

**To fix it easily**:
Just open your chrome browser's DevTool, click on setting's icon which lies in the same line of Console Tab Menu name.
It will open Settings, Click on Expermients & Type 'Pasting' in Filter (Refer below snapshot for the same)

***Path to Navigate***:
Open DevTool > Setting's icon > Experminets > Type 'Pasting' in Filter > Show warning about self-XSS when pasting code

**To Enable Paste Protection**, '**Check**' -> Show warning about self-XSS when pasting code.

**To Disable Paste Protection**, '**Uncheck**' -> Show warning about self-XSS when pasting code.

[image: Experminets Option of DevTool Settings]

***In your case, the Checkbox will be 'Unchecked' (Disable), Just 'Check' (Enable) it.***

***Now, open your chrome browser console & try pasting, it will not allow you to paste.***

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive guide. It looks like the right way to go. But I am afraid it does not work for me. I've enabled it. After that I still got no warnings when pasting. I will try again when I upgrade chrome.

Comment: Thank you so much. It has fixed the issue, and now I can paste data that are in the clipboard to the console.

Answer (score -1):

You can try searching for relevant flags in the "Chrome Flags" .

Open Chrome flags by typing `chrome://flags` into the address bar.
In the search box on the flags page, enter keywords related to clipboard or console behavior ("clipboard," "paste," or "console." etc.) or you can reset all flags [image: reset all flags]

Comment: [It's a DevTools Experiment](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-120#self-xss), not a Chrome Flags option - which is why you aren't seeing it.