# Can't paste code in Chrome DevTools

Tags: console, google-chrome

Today, I was trying to run code in the Chrome DevTools console (on macOS). While I was pasting a class-name, I got an error message:

> Warning: Do not paste code into the DevTools console that you do not
> understand or that you have not checked yourself. Such code may allow
> attackers to steal your identity or take over your computer. Type
> {PH1} below to allow pasting.

I tried following the instructions, by typing {PH1} and after that PH1. Both don't work; I have gotten the error message: VM876:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: PH1 is not defined at :1:3

[image: Screenshots with attempts and errors.]

I feel silly for even asking this, but I really don't know; what should I do so that I can execute code in Chrome DevTools again?

Comment: that looks like it is a placeholder, not the actual value. looks like a chrome bug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to re enable paste protection in Chrome console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77671024/how-to-re-enable-paste-protection-in-chrome-console)

Comment: or this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77587864/disable-paste-protection-in-chrome-devtools

Comment: Hi Daniel,

The first link you suggested contains this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77710155/1720311

It does not enable me to resolve this issue, but this does let me disable the function, which, in all fairness, I would have done anyway if I knew how to.

If you create a post containing this solution, I will mark it as the answer for you.